# Semaphore locking mechanism in Python

Tags: python, locking, python-multiprocessing, semaphore

I am currently working on a project which involves sharing of relay_CAN. i have to write a Python Script in order to lock the relay once it’s getting used by other device. the relay should be locked until its unlocked from another terminal. If I call any another device while its locked it should wait until unlocked. I've tried using, Lock (), Condition () but nothing seem to work. Any leads?

```py
sem = threading.Semaphore()

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--connect",
                        help="""connects devices""",
                        dest="connect")
    parser.add_argument("--disconnect",
                        help="""disconnects devices""",
                        dest="disconnect")
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()


    if args.connect:
        if sem.acquire(False):
            sem.acquire()
            print "locking.."
            try:
                #todo
            finally:
                print"locked successefully"
        else:
            print "pins are locked"
```

Comment: Can you post you tried code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for that. Check it now.

Comment: Then do the same, change your file_lock to .Semaphore(set_size) not .Lock() (supposed code cause didnt posted). Semaphore use Lock inside, is like a list of Lock to allow pass X

Comment: @Wonka I've tried .Semphore() also. Check the code now. I've posted it.

Comment: Yes I checked, but you miss some code, like Lock declaration. --> Semphore(2) will allow 2 pass inside. (default value is one, it will do same as lock).

Comment: @Wonka check now. When i am using .Semphore(1) it gets stuck after sem.acquire(). if I use .Semaphore(2) it doesnt acquire lock even after 2 inputs

Comment: How had you tested? I had tested just now and it works for my little lab